# how can I remove space between horizontal lines in apex chart(react)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I shared my code can anyone help me how can I remove spaces between lines like this in the image
[image]

here is my code
`

```
        options: {
            grid: {
                xaxis: {
                    lines: {
                        show: true,
                    },
                },
                yaxis: {
                    lines: {
                        show: false
                    }
                },
```

xaxis: {
axisTicks: {
show: false,
},
axisBorder: {
show: false
},
labels: {
show: false,
},}

`

Comment: Can you specify which spaces? What would the expect result look like?

Comment: @MaciejGol plot lines behind the bars the result looks like the picture I attach to this question

Answer (score 0):

In `plotOptions` set `barHeight` to `100%` https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/bar/#barHeight

```
plotOptions: {
  bar: {
    barHeight: "100%",
    horizontal: true
  }
},
```